# QCommandLineOption reading input files

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qcommandlineparser

I'm working on a code using QCommandLineOption to read input files (jpg files in this case). I'm trying to wrap my head around how to properly add the filepath & names to it to access the datas, but it doesn't work. Here's the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QCommandLineParser>
#include <QCommandLineOption>
#include <QString>
#include <QImage>
#include "imageconvert.h"
#include "clanu_process.h"

//--input=/Users/fakepath/coming-soon.jpg --     mask=/Users/fakepath/coming-soon_mask.jpg --output=/Users/fakepath/coming-soon_out_IFQ1.jpg

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    // ------------------------------------------
    //Command line parameters management
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("clanu-inpainting");
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationVersion("1.0");

    QCommandLineParser parser;
    parser.setApplicationDescription("Inpainting Console");
    parser.addHelpOption();
    parser.addVersionOption();

    QCommandLineOption inputFileOption(QStringList() << "i" << "input", "Fullpath and extension of the input <file>.", "file");
    parser.addOption(inputFileOption);

    QCommandLineOption maskFileOption(QStringList() << "m" << "mask", "Fullpath and extension of the mask <file>.", "file");
    parser.addOption(maskFileOption);

    QCommandLineOption outputFileOption(QStringList() << "o" << "output", "Fullpath and extension of the output <file>.", "file");
    parser.addOption(outputFileOption);

    // Process the actual command line arguments given by the user
    parser.process(app);

    QString inputFileName  = parser.value(inputFileOption);
    QString maskFileName   = parser.value(maskFileOption);
    QString outputFileName = parser.value(outputFileOption);

    std::cout << " input  " << inputFileName.toStdString()  <<  std::endl;
    std::cout << " output " << outputFileName.toStdString() <<  std::endl;
    std::cout << " mask   " << maskFileName.toStdString()   <<  std::endl;

    if(   maskFileName.isEmpty() ) { std::cout << "!! Mask is NOT SET and must be set!"   << std::endl; return -1; }
    if(  inputFileName.isEmpty() ) { std::cout << "!! Input is NOT SET and must be set!"  << std::endl; return -1; }
    if( outputFileName.isEmpty() ) { std::cout << "!! Output is NOT SET and must be set!" << std::endl; return -1; }

    std::cout << " - Input image file read : " << inputFileName.toStdString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - Mask image file read  : " << maskFileName.toStdString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - Output image file     : " << outputFileName.toStdString() << std::endl;
    // ------------------------------------------
return 0;
}
```

I'm getting "!! Mask is NOT SET and must be set!" when compiling, which means the string maskFileName is empty. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine. I just compiled it and tried, it works.

The problem is with the sample arguments you gave it:

```
--input=/Users/fakepath/coming-soon.jpg --     mask=/Users/fakepath/coming-soon_mask.jpg --output=/Users/fakepath/coming-soon_out_IFQ1.jpg
```

You need to remove the spaces in `--     mask`. So change ti to:

```
--input=/Users/fakepath/coming-soon.jpg --mask=/Users/fakepath/coming-soon_mask.jpg --output=/Users/fakepath/coming-soon_out_IFQ1.jpg
```

On a side note, when dealing with file path it's a good idea to wrap them in double quotes to allow for spaces in your path:

```
--input="/Users/fakepath/coming soon.jpg" --mask="/Users/fakepath/coming soon mask.jpg" --output="/Users/fakepath/coming soon out IFQ1.jpg"
```